# blocks in swift error

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am trying to convert my `objectiveC` application into `swift` and i am able to do it most of the things but here is some confusion ...

My `ObjectiveC` code is

```
-(void)getResponseFromURL:(NSString *)strURL 
  withParams:(NSMutableDictionary *)dictParams  
  success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject, bool isSuccess))blockSuccess  
  failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))blockFailure  
  showLoader:(BOOL)isShowDefaultLoader  
  showAnimated:(BOOL)isShowLoaderAnimated hideLoader:(BOOL)isHideDefaultLoader
  { //some code here }
```

My `Swift` code

```
func getResponseFromURL(strURL: String, withParams dictParams:Dictionary,  
Success:(operation:AFHTTPRequestOperation, responseobject:AnyObject, isSucces:Bool)->void, 
Failure:(operation:AFHTTPRequestOperation, error:NSError)->void,
showLoader isShowDefaultLoader:Bool,
showAnimated isShowLoaderAnimated:Bool, hideLoader isHideDefaultLoader:Bool){
    // Some code here
}
```

but it gives me some error
[image]

I think i missed some tricks...but i don't know what was that...
So how to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In Swift, use `Void`, not `void`
2. `Dictionary` in Swift is **Generic**, you need specify it as `Dictionary<AnyObject, AnyObject>` or use `NSDictionary` directly. You can convert `NSDictionary` to Swift `Dictionary` following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099165/how-do-i-convert-an-nsdictionary-to-a-swift-dictionarystring-nsobject)

**Update:**

Thanks to [Aviel Gross](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2242359/aviel-gross), use `[AnyObject: AnyObject]` instead of `Dictionary<AnyObject, AnyObject>`

As code of [WenchenHuang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3940672/wenchenhuang) shows, () is the same with `Void` in Swift, both represent empty tuple.

Comment: hmm...nice explaination

Comment: `Dictionary<AnyObject, AnyObject>` in new Swift syntax is `[AnyObject:AnyObject]`

Comment: Ok...thanks +1 for you answer and great explanation...and @WenchenHuang is also right in this case

Comment: `if let dictionary = dictParams {} else { // do what you want } ` or `if dictParams != nil { // do what you want }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77068/discussion-between-bhavin-and-boyi-li).

Answer (score 1):

In Swift it's `Void`. The "V" must be uppercase.

Comment: yes you are right and what about that dictionary error

Comment: I'll check it later on my Mac.

Answer (score 1):

```
  func getResponseFromURL(strURL: String, withParams dictParams:NSDictionary,
        Success:(operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation, responseobject:AnyObject, isSucces:Bool)->(),
        Failure:(operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation, error:NSError)->(),
        showLoader isShowDefaultLoader:Bool,
        showAnimated isShowLoaderAnimated:Bool, hideLoader isHideDefaultLoader:Bool){
            // Some code here
    }
```

Comment: why not void and why nsdictionary?

Comment: Dictionary is Generic, you can use Void,just because I like `()`

Comment: so () and Void gives same impact in swift

Comment: Yes,if you use block,it is fine.