# Cannot convert value of type '[NSObject : AnyObject]' to expected argument type '[String : AnyObject]'

Tags: swift, xcode7

Xcode7 and swift, My code:

```
func loadDefaults() {
    let settingBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Settings", ofType: "bundle")
    if settingBundle == nil {
        return
    }

    let root = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: settingBundle!.stringByAppendingString("Root.plist"))

    let prefrences = root?.objectForKey("PreferenceSpecifiers") as! Array<NSDictionary>

    let defautlsToRegister = NSMutableDictionary(capacity: root!.count)

    for prefrence in prefrences {
        let key = prefrence.objectForKey("Key") as! String!
        if key != nil {
            defautlsToRegister.setValue(prefrence.objectForKey("DefaultVale"), forKey: key!)
        }
    }

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(defautlsToRegister as [NSObject: AnyObject])
}
```

Problem code:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(defautlsToRegister as [NSObject: AnyObject])
```

building warnings

> Cannot convert value of type '[NSObject : AnyObject]' to expected argument type '[String : AnyObject]'

change code:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(defautlsToRegister as [String: AnyObject])
```

building warnings

> 'NSMutableDictionary' is not convertible to '[String : AnyObject]'

Please teach me how to do? thanks.

Comment: Please show example of `defautlsToRegister ` as type

Comment: Does using `as!` help, as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099165/how-do-i-convert-an-nsdictionary-to-a-swift-dictionarystring-nsobject?

Answer (score 5):

Your `defautlsToRegister` should be in the following format  `[String: AnyObject]`

Example: The following should work without warning

```
let defautlsToRegister = ["Test":10]
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(defautlsToRegister as [String: AnyObject])
```

Comment: Nailed it. Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed a simple thing about this error. I'm not sure if this the case but casting `String to NSString` seems to solve the problem for me. I found an explanation that `AnyObject` is a type alias to represent instances of any reference type, which is for example: `NSString`. But `String` is a `struct` so it can't be the reference type for `AnyObject`.

I see two ways for this:

First:

`let keyForMyKey: NSString = NSString(string: "mykey")
 let result = dict.objectForKey(keyForMyKey) as? NSMutableArray`

Second:

`let result = dict.objectForKey(NSString(string: "myKey")) as? NSMUtableArray`

More on the problem here: http://drewag.me/posts/swift-s-weird-handling-of-basic-value-types-and-anyobject

Answer (score 0):

For me this is worked.

```
let token = fields["X-AUTH-TOKEN"]! as? [[String : AnyObject]] //{
                // safe to use employees
                self.bindings.setObject(NSString(format: "%@", token!) as String, forKey: "X-AUTH-TOKEN")
```

Format(NSString method) will work in this scenario.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the reason for down voting @down voter?. For me the above code worked.